# ¿Como Puedo Ingresar La Hora En Django?

Tags: html, python, django, time

Necesito ayuda estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en la cual el usario ingresar una hora desde un formulario, e logrado que ingrese la fecha pero el cliente desea ingresar la hora en formato 2:00 pm, pero nunca e manejado un model para esta tarea alguien me puede ayudar como lo puedo realizar en django gracias

Bueno para aclarar un poco lo que el cliente quiere es poder ingresar la hora desde una pagina WEB en formato AM/PM, ejemplo las 2:30 PM, pero no se como crear el models este campo, en el momento cree hora = models.TimeField(), pero al llamarlo desde el Template solo me muestra un cuadro en blanco y al ingresar la hora no la almacena en la base de datos.

Lo que el cliente desea es una especie de reloj en la pagina web para ingresar la hora y luego con esta hora hacer una consulta estadistcia.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from datetime import datetime
from django import forms
from django.forms import extras
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from datetime import date
import datetime

# Create your models here.


class DatosCarpeta(models.Model):


    fecha = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d'])
    fechaf = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d'], blank=True, null=True)
    hora = models.TimeField(['%I:%H %p'], blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nuevafecha', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


from django import forms
from oficios.models import DatosCarpeta
import datetime
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.utils import timezone
from functools import partial
from django.conf import settings
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateTimeWidget
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    fecha=forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                    initial=timezone.now().date(),
                                    input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                    widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
    fechaf = forms.DateField(label=("Start date"),
                                    initial=timezone.now().date(),
                                    input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
                                    widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), required=False)

    hora=forms.TimeField(['%I:%H %p'])
    class Meta:
        model=DatosCarpeta
        fecha=forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS )
        fields = '__all__'


<html>
<head>
    {% load static from staticfiles %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static "css/oficios/css/style.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static "css/oficios/css/style.css" %}" type="text/css" media="all">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ingreso De Oficios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "jsq/jquery-ui.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "jsq/style.css" %}">
    <script src="{% static "jsq/jquery-1.12.4.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "jsq/jquery-ui.js"%}"></script>
    <script>
         $( function() {
            $( "input[name^=fecha]" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        } );
    </script>
    <script>
        function clicked(e)
        {
            if(!confirm('Desea Ingresar El Oficio'))e.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//widget.time.is/es.js"></script>
    <script>
        time_is_widget.init({Colombia_z11b:{template:"TIME<br>DATE", date_format:"year-monthnum-daynum"}});
    </script>
     <style>
            body{font:14px/1.5 "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif; padding:0 10px;}
            a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}

    </style>

    <title>Infreso De Oficios</title>

</head>



<body>
    <form action="{%  url 'carpetas' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<td><p align="center">{{form.hora}}</p></td>

         <div class="content1">
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar Oficio"  onclick="clicked(event)" >
            </div>     


    </section>  
    </form>


    <table align="center">
        <tr>

            <th></th>
            <th>
            <div style="text-align:center;width:250px;padding:1em 0;"> <h2><a style="text-decoration:none;"></h2> <iframe src="https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/clock-widget-iframe-v2?language=es&timezone=America%2FBogota" width="100%" height="150" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe> <small style="color:black;"></div>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>        
    </table>


    <form action="{%  url 'carpetas' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
         <table align="center">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                            <a href="/menu" > Menu <span class="icon octicon octicon-person"></span> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </table>    
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consulta [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) y si tienes algún problema, pregunta todo lo necesario y agrega un __[mcve]__ que muestre tu situación. Actualmente, tu pregunta es muy amplia.

Comment: Bueno en el models. py cree el parametro hora= models.TimeField(), lo llamo desde un Templete como {{forms.hora}}, pero solo me muestra un cuadro en blanco y al ingresar una hora no la almacena en al base de datos. Lo que el cliente solicita es poder ingresar la hora desde la pagina web en formato AM/PM, pero no se como hacerlo, como crear en el models un parametro que tome esta hora desde mi Template.

Comment: Te dejé un enlace a la documentación (lo repito: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats). En este enlace está explicado con claridad como se resuelve tu problema. La idea es que consultes la documentación y que intentes aplicarla a tu proyecto. Si tu implementación no funciona, se te pide que aclares con precisión y exactitud qué error tienes y que incluyas un pequeño ejemplo del código que utilizadas. Te recomiendo que leas esta guía: _[ask]_.

Comment: Gracias por la documentacion pero si soy muy honesto no entiendo mucho de la informacion que muestra por mas que la e leido, seguire buscando para ver si encuentro la solucion a mi problema gracias por su tiempo y disculpen las molestias

Comment: Pues suerte en tu búsqueda, aunque en el enlace que deje solo se trataba de hacer control-c control-v... pero suerte.